# UITableView ScrollView not called in iOS 10 devices

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift2, ios10

I have a `UITableView` in my application. When I run in the iOS 10 device, the `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` method is not calling and hence it is not scrolling even though I enabled the scrolling option in storyboard. It works as good in other iOS version. I have set the `scrollView` delegate as good. There is no error showing in the code. Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: try add the delegate function again, might be some typo or different function

Comment: did you set the `scrollview.delegate = self`.